# Merge dataframes by closest coordinates

Tags: python, pandas, fuzzy-comparison

Imagine we have 2 dataframes with coordinates ['X','Y']:

df1 :

```
 X            Y          House №
2531        2016           175
2219        2196           11
2901        3426           201
6901        4431           46
7891        1126           89
```

df2 :

```
 X            Y      Delivery office №
2534        2019            O1
6911        4421            O2
2901        3426            O3
7894.5      1120            O4
```

My idea is to merge them and get:

df3

```
 X            Y          House №    Delivery office №
2531        2016           175            01
2219        2196           11             NA
2901        3426           201            03
6901        4431           46             02
7891        1126           89             04
```

So we wants to realise 'fuzzy' merge by **threshold** (this param should be given by user). You can see that house number 11 didn't get any delivery office number because it located to much away from all of presented offices in df2.

So I need all rows from df2 'find' it's closest row from df1 and add it's 'Cost' value to it
You can see that usual in-box pd.merge do not work there as well as custom packages that realize fuzzy logic relates to string values using levenshtein distance and so on

Comment: what is the threshold when you say closet value

Comment: @anky_91 it's a great question. We have no threshold there. We want ALL df2's rows finds it's CLOSEST (in terms of coordinate distance) row from df1 (im not yelling ((:  )

Comment: @АндрейСевостьянов All houses are more or less closest in some sense... You need to define threshold. Or say 3-5-10 closest.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov you are right! sorry. We can set this param in func you would suggest)) But actually if we take into account aforementioned condition : rows from df2 have to be fully used in merging

Comment: then we would understand that we do not need threshold

Comment: (1) Do you mean you need cartesian merge between the two sorted by distance (2) Distance, euclidean?

Comment: BTW, why your "A" house has three different coordinates? Isn't it a mistake?

Comment: Let df1['Dist'] be shortest distance from that point from df1 to closest point from df2. Any ideas how to calculate that?

Comment: @АндрейСевостьянов There are many answers to the latest comment. The simplest is `math.dist()`. I believe you need more focus in asking your question.

Comment: @АндрейСевостьянов If you edit your question with answers to the questions raised in the comments I will vote for re-opening your question. If opened, I will post my answer to the question, as I understand it now, with resulting df having either all costs sorted by the desired distance, or any number of top n closest for every house of interest. Please, make it sure houses in "House" column have unique ID's/names.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov add some more details in example. Please comment if it helps

Comment: @АндрейСевостьянов Your question does not seem to be opening. You may try running `df1.assign(key=0).merge((df2.assign(key=0)), how = "outer", on="key",suffixes=("","_"))` and `from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist; df["distance"] = df.apply(lambda x: cdist([[x[0],x[1]]],[[x[4],x[5]]], metric="euclidean")[0][0], axis=1); 
df.drop(["X_","Y_","key"], axis=1, inplace=True); 
df.sort_values(["House", "distance"])` and `df.groupby("House").apply(lambda x: x.sort_values("distance").head(2).mean())` and report back if it helps.

Comment: This code will give you all the necessary tools and set you in the right direction. It can easily be adapted to a threshold param.

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov same approach was proposed on another resource. The problem is that I have df1 and df2 shaped like [10^5,:], so when I try merge (from your first batch of code) it crash because of memory error.

Comment: Run in a loop through `df1`

Comment: Actually I thought "apply lambda" function can solve my problem. We need calculate distance between first coordinates of each home and each delivery office and take then take minimum for each house. It looks really easy at the first sight...

Comment: It's O(n^2) problem. Either you do it at once under the hood and have enough memory or iterate through it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206150/discussion-between---and-sergey-bushmanov).

Answer (score 0):

No silver bullet, but a way to do this is to turn the Y values in categories using `pd.cut`.
Using this method, it will place the values in different bins. 
You need to tune the bins manually, for example set it at 20.

Load the data:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[2531, 2219, 2901, 6901, 7891], 'Y':[2016, 2196, 3426, 4431, 1126], 'House':['A', 'B', 'J', 'A', 'A']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'X':[2534, 6911, 2901, 7894.5], 'Y':[2019, 4421, 3426, 1120], 'Cost':[1200, 3100, 800, 600]})
```

Make new categories:

```
df1['Y2'] = pd.cut(df1['Y'], 20, labels=False)

df2['Y2'] = pd.cut(df2['Y'], 20, labels=False)

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Y2'], how='left')
```

Comment: @Андрей Севостьянов: does this help you?

Comment: thank you, a little bit confused how to select number of bins in a real data where we have 10^6 number as X and the same in Y

Comment: we apply pd.cut to different dataframes (with different range  (min and max values) of coordinates) so we would get different bins (or ranges if we set labels = True) for the same coordinates

Comment: @Андрей Севостьянов: sure, as indicated, my answer is no silver bullet, particularly if you have real data instead of integer and if the data becomes very large. Perhaps you should improve your question by giving more detail.